# How to combine 3 or 4 arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

I have three following arrays.

```
Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 295 )
Array ( [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg [1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg ) 
Array ( [0] => Seller Test Product [1] => Offline Product for Test )
```

The first array is the quantity, the second array is for the images, the third array is for the name of the products.
I want to combine all these three array into one and display it using foreach loop in PHP.

```
if I use array_merge(), I am getting the output:

Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 295 ) Array ( [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg [1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg ) Array ( [0] => Seller Test Product [1] => Offline Product for Test ) Array ( [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg [1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg [2] => Seller Test Product [3] => Offline Product for Test [4] => 395 [5] => 295 )
```

Now, how can I display it using foreach loop in the view.

in the view the code is :

```
<?php foreach($c as $key => $strs)
    {  ?>

    <img style="width:150px;" src="<?php echo @getimagesize(base_url("assets/upload/product/".$key)) ? base_url("assets/upload/product/".$key):'http://placehold.it/350x200';?>" class="img-responsive">
    <input type="text" name="vala" value="<?php echo $strs; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="valas" value="<?php echo $strss; ?>">

    <?php } ?>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: check out [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: What **exactly** should the resulting array look like?

Comment: `array_merge` is probably not what OP wants, it will just create an array of 6 elements without any relation.

Comment: If I use array_merge, I am getting something like this.    Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 295 ) Array ( [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg [1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg ) Array ( [0] => Seller Test Product [1] => Offline Product for Test ) Array ( [0] => 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg [1] => 5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg [2] => Seller Test Product [3] => Offline Product for Test [4] => 395 [5] => 295 )

Comment: How can I display in the following manner: <?php foreach($c as $key => $strs)
    {  ?>
    
 <img style="width:150px;" src="<?php echo @getimagesize(base_url("assets/upload/product/".$key)) ? base_url("assets/upload/product/".$key):'http://placehold.it/350x200';?>" class="img-responsive">
    <input type="text" name="vala" value="<?php echo $strs; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="valas" value="<?php echo $strss; ?>">

 <?php } ?>

Comment: @Shantanu please edit your question and add your expected output, it's not readable in the comments.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an _"X/Y Problem"_

Comment: It looks like you want to combine object values together, so a flat array is probably not a good idea. You can use a multi dimensional array, so every element contains a sub-array with your attributes or you can use a proper class to hold your attributes. Either way where do you get the 3 arrays from? Maybe you can begin a design change there if you have a way to get that info in a better way you don't have to convert it like that. Also a simple solution is to not use a for-each loop and just use index based access to all your arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you really want is to group all fields of all arrays together. Values with the same index shall be merged into a single object. [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used for this.

```
$final = array_map(function($quantity, $image, $name) {
        return (object)['quantity' => $quantity, 'image' => $image, 'name' => $name];
    }, $quantityArray, $imageArray, $nameArray);
```

The result will be:

```
[
    {
        'qunatity' => 395,
        'image' => '5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg',
        'name' => 'Seller Test Product'
    },
    {
        'qunatity' => 295,
        'image' => '5a3b602654cfd527057.jpeg',
        'name' => 'Offline Product for Test'
    }
]
```

You can then address them in your `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($final as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->image;
    echo $product->quantity;
}
```

---

For those of you who are in a real hurry, the following call to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will do the same trick, but without mapping the array fields to a specific key in the new multidimensional array:

```
$final = array_map(NULL, $quantityArray, $imageArray, $nameArray);
```

The result will be:

```
[
    [
        0 => 395,
        1 => '5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg',
        2 => 'Seller Test Product'
    ],
    [
        0 => 295,
        1 => '5a3b602654cfd527057.jpeg',
        2 => 'Offline Product for Test'
    ],
]
```

The inner arrays of the newly created mltidimensinal array will be filled in the order of which the arrays were provided to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works fine. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: this is the best answer among all.+1

Answer (score 1):

You can loop one array and use key to get the corresponding value from the other arrays.

```
$a=array ( 0 => 395,1 => 295 );
$b=array ( 0 =>" 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg" ,1 => "5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg" ) ;
$c=array ( 0 => "Seller Test Product",1 => "Offline Product for Test" );

Foreach($a as $key => $val){
    $res[$key]['qty'] = $val;
    $res[$key]['img'] = $b[$key];
    $res[$key]['desc'] = $c[$key];
}
Var_dump($res);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["qty"]=> int(395)
    ["img"]=> string(25) " 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg"
    ["desc"]=> string(19) "Seller Test Product"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["qty"]=> int(295)
    ["img"]=> string(23) "5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg"
    ["desc"]=> string(24) "Offline Product for Test"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/h8B0u

Answer (score -1):

**Example Code**

```
<?php
$array1=array ( 0 => 395,1 => 295 );
$array2=array ( 0 =>" 5a3a13f237715637629.jpeg" ,1 => "5a3b602654cfd527057.jpg" ) ;
$array3=array ( 0 => "Seller Test Product",1 => "Offline Product for Test" );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);print_r($array2);print_r($array3);
$result=array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);
print_r($result);
?>
```